# What follows after lexical analysis?

Tags: compiler, lexer

I'm working on a toy compiler (for some simple language like PL/0) and I have my lexer up and running. At this point I should start working on building the parse tree, but before I start I was wondering: How much information can one gather from just the string of tokens? Here's what I gathered so far:

1. One can already do syntax highlighting having only the list of tokens. Numbers and operators get coloured accordingly and keywords also.
2. Autoformatting (indenting) should also be possible. How? Specify for each token type how many white spaces or new line characters should follow it. Also when you print tokens modify an alignment variable (when the code printer reads "{" increment the alignment variable by 1, and decrement by 1 for "}". Whenever it starts printing on a new line the code printer will align according to this alignment variable)
3. In languages without nested subroutines one can get a complete list of subroutines and their signature. How? Just read what follows after the "procedure" or "function" keyword until you hit the first ")" (this should work fine in a Pascal language with no nested subroutines)
4. In languages like Pascal you can even determine local variables and their types, as they are declared in a special place (ok, you can't handle initialization as well, but you can parse sequences like: "var a, b, c: integer")
5. Detection of recursive functions may also be possible, or even a graph representation of which subroutine calls who. If one can identify the body of a function then one can also search if there are any mentions of other function's names.
6. Gathering statistics about the code, like number of lines, instructions, subroutines

EDIT: I clarified why I think some processes are possible. As I read comments and responses I realise that the answer depends very much on the language that I'm parsing.

Comment: No, you cannot do any decent highlighting using just tokens - you'll miss all the context-sensitive semantics. Autoidentation is not possible as well, you'll need some semantic information. And, what's the point? In the modern parsing approaches you'll even skip lexing altogether.

Comment: Exactly: you can't highlight calls to static functions differently from calls to non-static ones (or highlight calls to non-existing functions!). All of those require semantic information (which is also why they are often not implemented in pure text editors, even if they do basic syntax highlighting).

Comment: @SK-logic: Not sure what "modern parsing approaches" you're thinking of, but skipping the lexing phase and trying to fold all that logic into the parser itself is [a great way to screw it up](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/449/how-not-to-write-a-parser).

Comment: @MasonWheeler, you're wrong, and your link does not prove anything (besides DBXJSON authors ignorance). All the PEG-based parsers are naturally lexerless, and it is really great. Now you're not limited to a boring, flat sequence of tokens - you can easily mix different languages in a single input stream. And it benefits even things like parsing `printf` format strings, not just advanced languages like Katahdin.

Comment: @MasonWheeler, handling whitespaces in lexerless parsers is trivial. In my Packrat implementation I introduced a special "token" entity, which inserts the current `whitespace*` before the token code (and it is ignored by the memoisation, which allows some  interesting further optimisations). As a side effect - you can even mix languages with the different whitespace definitions. Another useful side effect - trivial handling of the nested comments.

Comment: "you can easily mix different languages": From a formal language point of view, the union or intersection of different languages is just another language. In this respect, I do not see how skipping the lexical analysis phase can make parsing easier.

Comment: @Giorgio, an identifier in one language can be a special token in the other. A comment block in one language (say, Pascal) can be a code block in the other (say, C). You cannot mix the two if you're using a single lexer.

Comment: @delnan, I never had any problems with it in my practice. I'm translating verbatim BNF specifications of the languages into PEG and just works. A no-brainer, really. And, by the way, this approach simplifies significantly things like ECMAscript weird semicolon handling.

Comment: @SK-logic: You just need to choose the right tokens. If you want to mix Pascal and C you have to use individual tokens '{' and '}' instead of making all the string between '{' and '}' a single token.

Comment: @Giorgio, you're so wrong. How can you define a comment (i.e., a whitespace token) this way?!? Your Pascal parser will choke on these `{` `}` tokens. There is absolutely no way to unify two different languages' sets of tokens. A single token in one language will be many different tokens in the other. Think of, say, Verilog numeric constants. And, needless to mention, you won't be able to extend your language with the new syntax dynamically if you're using a dedicated lexing pass.

Comment: @SK-logic: A Pascal + C parser (Pascal + C is the language you want to parse, right?) will handle the tokens properly. I really do not see your problem. The union of two context free languages is context free. Of course you might have ambiguities (there might be more than one parse tree for a given string even if the grammars for the individual languages were not ambiguous), but how does removing lexical analysis solve ambiguity?

Comment: @Giorgio, think again. You're missing the point. How your pascal will parse the following? `BEGIN { IDENT-a < IDENT-Type1 > IDENT-b ( HEXCONSTANT-ff ) } PRINTLN ( PASCALSTRING-abc ) END `

Comment: @Giorgio, and yes, removing this totally useless lexing pass solves the ambiguity issue as well as many other problems. Take a look at Katahdin, Fortress and PFront, for example.

Comment: @SK-logic: Of course the Pascal + C parser will parse it as an empty Pascal block (containing only a comment). Since it is not a valid C piece of code it won't parse it as C code. If it were, you would have an ambiguous language (one string has two parse trees). If your resulting language (e.g. Pascal + C) is ambiguous (you cannot tell apart the two sub-languages because their intersection is non-empty) it is such for any CF grammar so removing lexical analysis won't remove the ambiguity.

Comment: I am assuming that you want to parse CF languages. Maybe my assumption is not correct (?)

Comment: @Giorgio, you still not getting it. It is a sequence of *TOKENS*. Coming from your unified lexer. Now, please write down a BNF which will be able to handle such a stream. And then, a next task: try to mix C and Python. And another point: something can be an illegal token in one language and perfectly legal in another.

Comment: @Giorgio, I pointed you to the languages which do resolve this ambiguity easily. Why are you still insisting that lexerless parsing won't resolve it? Remember, in a lexerless parsing tokens are context-sensitive. Inside a C context you won't even try parsing Pascal tokens.

Comment: @SK-logic: I think we are comparing apples with oranges: I was talking about parsing a context free language. If you are parsing context-sensitive languages you probably have other techniques.

Comment: @Giorgio, again, parse a mixture of C and Python. Both are "context free". A mixture is not. Another, more practical example: mixing SQL into any other language. Please, take a look at the languages I've mentioned above, I hope then you'll understand the value of lexerless parsing.

Comment: @Giorgio the union of two context free languages is not necessarily context free. besides which most languages are not context free, if they do use a CFG they usually do a bunch of post processing

Comment: "the union of two context free languages is not necessarily context free.": What??? See e.g. Hopcroft, Motwani, Ullman, "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation" (Addison Wesley, 2001) ISBN 0-201-44124-1, Theorem 7.24, page 284.

Comment: @SK-logic: How is the "mixture" of two CF languages defined?

Comment: @Giorgio, imagine, say, C, where in place of expression you can also use a SQL statement. You're talking about irrelevant things here, because you've excluded the lexing from your grammar definition. That theorem does not say anything about unifying lexers, it implies that two CF languages are based on the same set of tokens (which is definitely not the case). Have you already checked out Katahdin?

Comment: I have looked at it. So I want to mix Java and PHP now. I want to parse and evaluate the expression `"1" + 1` in my Java-PHP mixture. Can I do it in Katahdin? What is the result?

Comment: @Giorgio, of course you have to add some syntactic clues to distinguish one language from another. Like in case with C and SQL - it is always obvious which language is used (if you're using an infinite lookahead as in Packrat).

Answer (score 2):

You've got one minor problem with your definitions there. Auto-formatting and recursive function definition (and even variable detection) should not be possible in a lexer, because a lexer, by definition, is linear and context free.  Its job is to read, identify and validate one single token, and then do it again and again and again until reaching the end of the file, and that's it.

Any recursive analysis, and anything that requires remembering state from before the beginning of the current token is beyond the scope of a lexer and should be undertaken in the parser instead.  This separation of concerns makes your code cleaner and less likely to contain subtle bugs that are hard to track down.

Comment: actually a lexer is regular ;), the syntax tree (in the parser) will be a context-free grammar

Comment: @RatchetFreak: I know.  But each level of restrictions includes the restrictions of the level before.  Therefore, all regular grammars must be not only linear, but also context free, which is the point I was making.